# Replace SSL certificate in Apache vhosts-file using sed

Tags: regex, apache, sed

I have a cron job that runs dehydrated to renew Let's Encrypt certificates on my QNAP webserver.

I want it to fetch the current vhosts file that is generated by QNAP, get the section for the actual site, and then replace that information with correct certificate data.

Here is a section of the vhosts-file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
<Directory "/share/Web/domains">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/share/Web/domains"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:!MD5
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/stunnel/uca.pem"
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
<Directory "/share/Web/someotherdir">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
    ServerName www.anotherexample.com
    DocumentRoot "/share/Web/someotherdir"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:!MD5
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/stunnel/uca.pem"
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

Using this file, I've managed to put together a small command to replace it with the new information:

```
unchanged_cert() {
local DOMAIN="${1}" KEYFILE="${2}" CERTFILE="${3}" FULLCHAINFILE="${4}" CHAINFILE="${5}"

# This hook is called once for each certificate that is still
# valid and therefore wasn't reissued.
#
# Parameters:
# - DOMAIN
#   The primary domain name, i.e. the certificate common
#   name (CN).
# - KEYFILE
#   The path of the file containing the private key.
# - CERTFILE
#   The path of the file containing the signed certificate.
# - FULLCHAINFILE
#   The path of the file containing the full certificate chain.
# - CHAINFILE
#   The path of the file containing the intermediate certificate(s).

#Prepare new values
lead='ServerName '${DOMAIN}'$'
tail='^<\/VirtualHost>$'
insert='\ \       SSLEngine on \
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:!MD5 \
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 \
    SSLCertificateChainFile "'${FULLCHAINFILE}'" \
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "'${KEYFILE}'" \
    SSLCertificateFile "'${CERTFILE}'"'

#Insert new values to VHOSTS-file
#NOTE: command must be on 2 lines
sed -e "/$lead/,/$tail/{ /$lead/{p; i $insert
}; /$tail/p; d }" --in-place /etc/config/apache/extra/httpd-ssl-vhosts-user.conf
}
```

It works, **but** it removes the *DocumentRoot "/share/Web/domains"*-line which is cruial for the server to operate.
I'm not that good at sed, but I hope that there's a way to ignore the deletion of this row. I just can't figure out how.

Can someone guide me in the right direction? Since the server hosts multiple domains I can't hard code it like some other variables.

Comment: Try awk. Something like: Set variables for `"${insert}"`, the first and last line to match. Toggle a boolean when the lead is found, use `next;` when the line has `SSL`and print additional lines before the `tail` and toggle again. `awk` can use 2 inputfiles, so you can store the first file in an array and paste that array before the tail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i "/$lead/,/$tail/{/SSL/d};/DocumentRoot/a$insert" /etc/config/apache/extra/httpd-ssl-vhosts-user.conf
```

Delete the SSL lines first, then append the insert text after DocumentRoot line.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't solves the problem, since it's replacing the SSL-configuration on all other vhosts as well.

Comment: It worked when I tested it locally with some other virtual hosts. Can you post a sample of the file with additional vhosts?

Comment: I've updated the example now, when running your query, the SSL-lines are updated on both the www.example.com site and www.anotherexample.com

Comment: Perhaps repeat the range like `sed -i "/$lead/,/$tail/{/SSL/d};/$lead/,/$tail/{/DocumentRoot/a$insert}" /etc/config/apache/extra/httpd-ssl-vhosts-user.conf`